# Ngxs + WebSocket | How to listen the socket events at client?

Tags: websocket, ngxs

I am using [Ngxs/websocket-plugin](https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/websocket) in my project.

I connected the WebSocket with

```
this.store.dispatch(new ConnectWebSocket());
```

and dispatching the socket messages with

```
sendMessage(from: string, message: string) {
    const event = new SendWebSocketMessage({
      type: 'message',
      from,
      message
    });

    this.store.dispatch(event);
  }
```

The socket events are being received on the server **but I am not getting how to listen to the socket event at the client?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket messages are being dispatched in the store by the `ngxs/websocket-plugin`.

This plugin will **receive** a message from the server and **dispatch** the message as an action with the corresponding type value. If the type property doesn't match any **client-side @Action methods** (with an Action with the corresponding static type property value) then no State will respond to the message.